# How to accessibly inject an applet onto a page using a button?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

In an HTML page, I have a `<button>`. Clicking it, javascript injects an applet into a `<div>` elsewhere on the page. Clicking it again hides the div. More clicking toggles it. (If it matters, it is a [GeoGebra applet](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Reference:GeoGebra_Apps_Embedding).)

I have some questions about how to do this kind of thing accessibly. I'm hoping some accessibility gurus here may have answers.

1. My button has a title "Show calculator" and that toggles to "Hide calculator" when pushed. Is there anything more to do with button attributes?
2. Is it correct to inject the applet into a `<div>`, instead of, say, an HTML `<object>`?
3. When the button is pushed, can focus stay on the button or should it move to the applet? If focus stays on the button, do I need to provide some easy way for a screen reader user to jump to the applet? And if so, how to communicate that way to the user? Should I provide an easy way to get focus back from the applet to the button?
4. For this kind of thing, should there be aria attributes on the `<div>`? Is there an appropriate aria role? And is it appropriate for this situation use an aria live region announcing the showing/hiding of the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the best accessibility experience, you should follow the [disclosure widget pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#disclosure).

To answer your specific questions.

1. The disclosure pattern talks about the ARIA attributes that should be set on your button.
2. Sorry, that’s not related to accessibility so I can’t answer it.
3. In general, you should not move the focus after selecting the button.  If you do, it might violate [WCAG 3.2.2 On Input](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/consistent-behavior-unpredictable-change.html), *“unless the user has been advised of the behavior before using the component”*.
     As far as letting the user know how to get to the applet, if you follow the disclosure widget pattern, they will hear “expanded” or “collapsed” when you change the value of `aria-expanded` so the user will know that something follows.  Is your applet immediately following the button in the DOM?  That would be the best solution.  If there are elements between the button and the newly injected applet, that could be confusing.
4. `aria-live` can be very handy, but in this case, should not be necessary if #3 is followed.

Comment: Thanks, and I will move the applet to immediately following the button in the DOM.